# How to insert a UTF-8 character onto an image

Tags: python, matplotlib, n-queens

I created a chessboard with Python using Matplotlib and I want to know if it's possible to add an image in the squares I want.

I'm trying to replicate the 8-queens problem but with variable size, but my main problem is that I'm not sure how to show the queen in each square of the chessboard.

```
chessboard = np.zeros((size,size))

chessboard[1::2,0::2] = 1
chessboard[0::2,1::2] = 1

print(chessboard)
plt.imshow(chessboard,cmap='binary')
plt.show()
```

My plan is to create another `np.zeros()` with the same size but this time I will represent my queens.

Comment: Does https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo.html help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could plot a centered "text" with a [UTF-8 queen character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode#Unicode_code_points_and_HTML). You need to change the text color when printing on a black background.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

size = 8
chessboard = np.zeros((size,size))

chessboard[1::2,0::2] = 1
chessboard[0::2,1::2] = 1

plt.imshow(chessboard, cmap='binary')

for _ in range(20):
    i, j = np.random.randint(0, 8, 2)
    plt.text(i, j, '♕', fontsize=20, ha='center', va='center', color='black' if (i - j) % 2 == 0 else 'white')

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Nice :) But of course you should use Unicode [U+265B  ♛](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/265b/index.htm) on the white tiles.

Comment: The black queen looks rather white when using a white font color. So, hard to put on a black background. Probably something like yellow and brown as background makes more sense when having both white and black pieces. Or white and grey squares as on the wikipedia page.