# how I can resize an image based on the size of a cell in a table with numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want an image to be placed in a box on a board, and the image to be the size of the cell. I have this code, but when I create a board larger than 8 x 8, the image doesn't change in size.

```
import  numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, OffsetImage

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

n = 8
tablero = np.zeros((n,n), dtype = int)

tablero[::2, 1::2] = 1
tablero[1::2, ::2] = 1
#tablero.shape

print(tablero)
plt.imshow(tablero, cmap='gray')


reina = mpimg.imread("C:\\Users\\hirof\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Python_logica_2\\Proyecto", format = "png")
reina.thumbnail((2, 2))
imagebox = OffsetImage(reina, zoom=0.01)
imagebox.image.axes = axes
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox,[2,5])
axes.add_artist(ab)

plt.axis()
plt.show()
```

Also when I used `reina = mpimg.imread("C:\\Users\\hirof\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Python_logica_2\\Proyecto"`, format = "png")` the compiller return me  [Errno 13] Permission denied, and I used the comand chmod and I can't fix this problem

Comment: For you `imread` you probably need to provide the full filename. The string gives the impression that it is only the directory name.

Comment: To place an image in a cell, instead of `AnnotationBbox`, it is easier to use `imshow` again, but with `extent=(x0,x1,y0,y1)`.  A problem with `imshow` is that you need to set the xlim and ylim again afterwards.

Comment: To draw chess pieces, it is much easier to use the UTF-8 characters. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode  With most editors you can just copy-paste the chess piece similar to a text.  And then position it with `ax.text(x, y, '♕', ha='center', va='center')`.  See also [Insert Queen on a chessboard with pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608055/insert-queen-on-a-chessboard-with-pyplot/60608673#60608673)